# matriz gerar numero aleatorio de 0 ate 99 sem repetição Visualg

Tags: visualg

Ja tinha feito a pergunta mas informei a questão errada. Enfim, preciso fazer um programa para gerar automaticamente números entre 0 e 99 de uma
cartela de bingo (5x5) e nao pode gerar números repetidos dentro das cartelas
Ja tendei mta coisa e até agora nda ta funcionando e nao consegui entender os exemplos q procurei (q estão geralmente em C) 
ULTIMA COISA Q EU FIZ ...

```
 para i de 0 ate 4 passo 1 faca
       para j de 0 ate 4 passo 1 faca
            se (cartela[i,j]+1 <> cartela[i,j]) entao
            cartela[i,j] <- randi(99)
            fimse
       fimpara
  fimpara

  para i de 0 ate 4 passo 1 faca
       para j de 0 ate 4 passo 1 faca
            escreva(cartela[i,j])
       fimpara
       escreval("")
  fimpara
```

Comment: Pela matemática que conheço cartela[i,j]+1 será sempre diferente de cartela[i,j]. Seu comando SE não tem sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, a cada número gerado você pode percorrer toda a sua matriz, para verificar se o número já não foi inserido, caso ele não tenha inserido você o insere, mas caso ele já tenha sido inserido você gera outro

```
Algoritmo "stackoverflow"
Var
    //Declaração das variáveis
    cartela : vetor[0..4,0..4] de inteiro
    i,j,m, n, numero, controlador:inteiro
Inicio
    para i de 0 ate 4 passo 1 FACA
        para j de 0 ate 4 passo 1 FACA
            numero <- randi(99) //gera o número randomico
            controlador <- 0 //controlador para verificar se o numero já foi inserido
            enquanto controlador = 0 faca
                controlador <- 1
                //bloco para verificar toda a matriz
                para m de 0 ate 4 passo 1 FACA
                    para n de 0 ate 4 passo 1 FACA
                        se cartela[m,n] = numero entao //caso o numero já exista
                            numero <- randi(99) //gera o novo número randomico
                            controlador <- 0 //reinicia o controlador para verificar se o novo número existe
                        fimse
                    fimpara
                fimpara
            fimenquanto
            cartela[i,j] <- numero //ao sair do enquanto, é garantido que o número não existe na matriz, então adiciona esse número a matriz.
        fimpara
    fimpara
    para i de 0 ate 4 passo 1 FACA
       para j de 0 ate 4 passo 1 FACA
           escreva(cartela[i,j])
       fimpara
       escreval()
    fimpara
Fimalgoritmo
```